# Why wont ServerSocket.accept() work?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

Before I ask this question I would to apologise because of the fact that I have no idea what has gone wrong here, so I'm just saying in advanced that this may be a pain in the neck to follow.

```
public void setUp(){
    try {
        port = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the port to host server on"));
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println(server.getLocalPort());
        connection = server.accept();
        out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        connected = true;
        loop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        connected = false;
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong there, be sure to use syntax:\nport: 1337\nMaybe the selected port is in use?");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

The code above should make it so that i can set up a basic server that any client can connect to, I don't think the client code is relevant at this time, but if it is needed then please ask.

anyway, my question, when I call this method it runs fine until it hits

```
connection = server.accept();
```

and then the method just ends as if I typed return;  !

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to fix it?

Also note

port = Integer for the port
server = ServerSocket
connection = Socket
out = PrintWriter
in = BufferedReader
connected = boolean

Comment: Maybe it only looks like it ends because `connection = server.accept();` will make thread wait till client connect. Do you have some error message?

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look into that.

Comment: Ahh, post that as an answer so I can accept it, thanks a lot this community never lets me down! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it only looks like it ends because `connection = server.accept();` will make thread wait till client connects.